# Magento Category Flat Data will not reindex error 'There was a problem with reindexing process.'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento

I have recently moved a magento installation of version 1.5.0.1 to a live server however no products are showing on the front end. After inspecting the indexes i see that the Category Flat Data index is needs re-indexing however when trying to re-index this i get an error notice box saying  'There was a problem with reindexing process.'

So far i have tried the following

1. Resetting file permissions 755 for folders, 664 for files

   find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

   find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
2. Deleting the contents of the var folder including cache and locks folders
3. trying to process the indexes manually through the console using the command below from public_html/shell

   > php indexer.php reindexall

I have inspected the error logs and the following is present

```
2011-09-26T08:16:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
`store_id` smallint(5) unsigned not null default '0',
`all_children` text defau' at line 10
Trace: #0 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#3 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(526): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#5 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(433): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#6 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(237): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->rebuild()
#7 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#8 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#9 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#10 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#11 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#12 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/bboutique/www.bassboutique.co.uk/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Ian

Comment: I've had problems with some rogue SQL statements that required me to go down into the database methods and just print out the statement so I could see where the problem was. You might have to throw some `print $sq;` calls in there to see what the offending statement is.

Comment: As @jprofitt said, go to file `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php`, line 526 and echo generated create table query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same errors loading Magento's sample data into Magento 1.5.1.0 (Despite what Varien say, their sample data *does not* work with all Magento versions)

in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php I found this on line 549:

```
switch ($column['DATA_TYPE']) {
                case 'smallint':
                case 'int':
                    $_type = $column['DATA_TYPE'] . '(11)';
                    $_is_unsigned = (bool)$column['UNSIGNED'];
                    if ($column['DEFAULT'] === '') {
                        $column['DEFAULT'] = null;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'varchar':.........................
```

there was no case statement for 'timestamp'; a datatype that Magento uses for it's 'updated_at' and 'created_at' columns in Magento 1.6.1.0

I did some alter table statements to change the 'timestamp' columns in catalog_category_entity and catalog_product_entity to 'datetime' and the indexing problem disappeared.

I have now done a find and replace on all 'timestamp' columns in the sample data to make it compatible with 1.5.1.0

I hope this helps someone :)